# How to search for key words using Solr from crawled web pages by nutch?

Tags: solr, nutch

I have an application which crawls over the websites using Apache Nutch 2.1 and persisting data to the MySQL. I have to integrate Nutch and Solr which is not a problem as enough documentation is available on the internet.

After storing content from webpages, i want to add a search functionality based on Solr. I need to search for key words in the webpages. For example, if i am crawling websites which are movies related and i want to search for any specific movie(as a key word) from the crawled data, what are the changes i need to make to the Solr configurations. Do i need to write a separate plugin altogether or i can use existing plugins?What type of indexing i have to add to the solr configurations?

Comment: Did you try anything or are you asking before you read the relevant documentation?

Comment: Yes..i have gone through the blogs and articles and most of them talk about metadata-plugin to the nutch-site.xml or html tags adding to the solr config.xml which is not my case.

Comment: I have also gone through the documents related to the creation of customized plugin and given a situation i dont have any problem with it. I am looking for a direction.

Comment: If the content being indexed does contain these keywords you are looking for, all you need is a straightforward integration of nutch+solr. Solr indexes your content so it you'll be able to search normally; unless, of course, if your definition of keywords is something else.

Comment: For indexing, i need to integrate solr to my application. I want to understand the indexing criteria? Where to add keywords for indexing in solr configuration?

Comment: In the above movie example..do i need to add all movie names as a keyword in order to search them out

Comment: Yes @abhijeet, that would be one of the tokens you'd specifically index, because if the user's query matches with the movie name you want this page to be at the top. By indexing this separately, you can modify the ranking algorithm to bias for this element.